# User-friendly HTML editor for non-webdesigners

Tags: gratis, html-editor, css

This software should:

- work on Windows and Linux systems
- create and edit
- save locally
- allow the applying of HTML tags and customised classes
- generate clean HTML documents
- free

Comment: Are you looking for a WYSIWYG editor (hence "non-webdesigners"?), or do you want to write the HTML code yourself? -- And as you tagged your question with [tag:css], does it mean you want to provide/write the CSS yourself, or should the editor create CSS automatically?

Comment: This editor has to build a html file just like MS Word make a doc file. I work with instructional designers that don't know how to deal with html/css. In the other hand, I need to get this text/html file after beeing written and do some visual/semantic edition. Now I'm testing an editor called Komposer. It seems to be nice since the intructional designer can type the text applying tag's without working on de "matrix" view ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/download.php) is the best. Simple, has Multi-OS support, Multilanguage, handles CSS, ... And it's free. However: Save every 10 minutes (at least), and program restart is recommended once per hour. Enjoy programming! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com/3) is by far the best code editor I've ever used (not free but there's a trial), then [atom.io](https://atom.io/) comes close second.